# Function notation issue

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have no idea what this means and can't find anything after researching on the internet:-

$f: A\to B$ is a function under which each element of set $A$ has an **image** in set B

$f: x\mapsto y$ is a function under which $x$ is **mapped** to $y$.

Please help. Also, do the use of different words 'mapped' and 'image' indicate anything?

Comment: They both essentially mean the same thing as $f(x)=y$ or $f(A)=B$

Comment: @RhysHughes $f(A) \subset B$.  Consider $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R:x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: "mapped to" is a verb.  "image" is a noun.  $A$ and $B$ are sets of elements.  $x$ and $y$ are individual elements.  Both sentences are saying the same thing.  All the elements of $A$ are being mapped to some of the elements of $B$.  When $x \in A$ is mapped to $y \in B$ we say that $y$ is the image of $x$ and we say do collection of all the mapped to elements is called "The image of $A$". We use the notation $f(A)$ to indicate all the mapped to points.  Note: $f(A) \subset B$ but $B$ might (or might not) be bigger than $f(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

"$\mapsto$" describes what is happening on the *individual element* level. E.g., the notation $$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto x^2$$ describes **the squaring function on the reals**: the first bit tells us the domain and codomain, and the second bit tells us exactly what it does.

Note that both pieces are necessary (barring context clues): just writing "$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$" wouldn't let me figure out that $f(2)=4$, and just writing "$f:x\mapsto x^2$" wouldn't tell me that $f$ is a function from reals to reals (as opposed, say, to being defined on the complex numbers).

---

As to "image" versus "mapped to," the distinction is grammatical: noun versus verb. We can say e.g. that the image of $2$ under $f$ (in the above example) is $4$, or that $2$ is mapped to $4$, but we can't say e.g. that the mapped to of $2$ is $4$ or that $2$ is imaged $4$.

Answer (score 1):

====short ====

"mapped to" is a verb.  "image" is a noun.  $A$ and $B$ are sets of elements.  $x$ and $y$ are individual elements.  Both sentences are saying the same thing.  All the elements of $A$ are being mapped to some of the elements of $B$.  When $x \in A$ is mapped to $y \in B$ we say that $y$ is the image of $x$ and the collection of all the "mapped to elements" is called "The image of $A$". We use the notation $f(A)$ to indicate all the mapped to points.  Note: $f(A) \subset B$ but $B$ might (or might not) be bigger than $f(A)$.

==== long =====

$A$ is a collection of lots of points/numbers/elements.  Each of these points/elements/numbers are mapped to a single point/element/number in the collection $B$.

The first sentence $f:A\to B$ says: we are mapping *all* the elements of $A$ to some or maybe to all elements of $B$.

The second sentence $f:x \mapsto y$ says: we are mapping the *single* element $x\in A$ to the single element $y \in B$.  In other words, $f(x) = y$.

We can say that $x$ maps to $y$ or we can say that: when $x$ gets mapped, $x$ will have an image $y$ which is the element $x$ gets mapped to.

That is all about single individual elements.

Now $A$ is called the *domain* and every element of $A$ is mapped to some element of $B$.

$B$ is called either the *range* (if you learned math before 1985) or the *co-domain* (if you learned math after 1985), and it is the big set that contains all the elements that all of $A$ is mapped to.

The collection of all the points that $A$ gets mapped to is also called the *image* of $A$ and just as $A$ is the collection of all the points that are going to be mapped, the *image* of $A$ is the collection of all the images of points that have been mapped into $B$.

But note:  Although all to elements of $A$ are mapped to $B$, not all the elements of $B$ need to be mapped to.  $B$ might be bigger than than image of $A$ and have points that were *not* mapped to.

Example:

$f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $f: x \mapsto x^2$.  Every element of $\mathbb R$ gets mapped to an element of $\mathbb R$ but only non-negative elements are mapped to.  There is no $x$ so that $x\mapsto -5$.  So the *image* of $\mathbb R$ is $[0,-\infty)\subset\mathbb R$.